# Excel macro for checking existence of file

Tags: vba, excel

I don't have any understanding of VBA. I have excel file which contains File path and I want to find existence of file in that location.

I tried the following but need something better than this

```
Sub Test_File_Exist_With_Dir()
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim TestStr As String

    FilePath = ActiveSheet.Range("A7").Value

    TestStr = ""
    On Error Resume Next
    TestStr = Dir(FilePath)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If TestStr = "" Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("B7").Value = 0
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Range("B7").Value = 1
    End If

End Sub
```

Expected output

```
    File path                       Existence
    C:\Users\Desktop\Excel\Jan15.txt    1
    C:\Users\Desktop\Excel\Feb15.txt    1
    C:\Users\Desktop\Excel\Mar15.txt    1
    C:\Users\Desktop\Excel\Apr15.txt    0
    C:\Users\Desktop\Excel\May15.txt    0
```

If I add new row to data then its existence should automatically populate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yau can **use this as a function directly in your workbook** as a classic Excel formula, just type `=File_Exist(A1)` and this will work as a normal function (you can autofill next rows easily).

```
Public Function File_Exist(ByVal FilePath As String) As Integer
    On Error Resume Next

    Dim TestStr As String
    TestStr = Dir(FilePath)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If TestStr <> "" Then
        File_Exist = 1
    Else
        File_Exist = 0
    End If

End Function
```

If you want to test existence automatically and populate every time you add new row to data then you'll have to use `Worksheet_SelectionChange` but it'll be more difficult than this and not so useful if you have a practical function!

Comment: As a minor addition you can add
     Application.Volatile True
At the start of the function. This will make the function more dynamic as it does not depend on manually refreshing the worksheet. It may make the workbook a little slower though.

Comment: Ok, that I can do manually but this is giving same output for all.

Comment: Personally I would drop the `On Error` to see what is happening in debug and is your workbook in auto calculation mode? Press F9 to recalculate workbook or Shift+F9 to recalculate only the active sheet! ;)

Comment: you changed the function name, so the return should be changed too. Fix: `Test_File_Exist_With_Dir =` -> `File_Exist =`

Comment: @ya_dimon : what a rookie mistake!^^ Thx for pointing it out!

Comment: @Sangram : It seems that I was a bit distracted, my bad. Try the edit! ;)

Comment: To use this, place it in a regular module and you can use it by code or in the worksheet directly (which would be the simplest solution for your issue I think)

Comment: After function name is it required to write `As Integer`. If I remove that what will it affect?

Comment: If I'm correct, nothing, you just won't have any kind of output validation. But in my opinion, this should be declared `As Boolean` with outputs TRUE and FALSE. Is it working fine for you now?